Static files in Django
I am trying to create a Django project. I created the application under the name blog. In it I have created static and templates folders. static folder has CSS folder where CSS file. It is attached to an HTML template, but none of the CSS styles work when running the localhost.8000 server.
Simple HTML
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>

Simple CSS
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 35px;
}

I found that the problem occurs when I add "localhost:8000" or "127.0.0.1" to the ALLOWED_HOSTS list in my settings.py file.
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost:8000", "127.0.0.1"]


share the urls.py?

This question is similar to: Why is my static CSS not working in Django?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

please share settings.py entries regarding your static settings.

minus one for lack of responsiveness.

Some configuration is required to load static files.
# settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'blog/static']
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# urls.py

from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static('media/', document_root=(settings.BASE_DIR / 'media/'))


(1)
Firstly is your css file named styles.css ?
(2)
Is your folder structure similar to as follows:
blog/
static/
css/
styles.css
templates/
your_template.html
(3)
Does this reflect your settings.py:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'  # Base URL for static files
Ensure STATICFILES_DIRS is correctly set
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "blog" / "static",
]

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


Yes. My CSS file named styles.css
The file path is right
Yes the line STATIC_URL = '/static/' is default in settings.py

